# Shopify Liquid finding out date of a specific day of the week

Tags: shopify, liquid

Wondering if someone could help with a question on Liquid / Shopify. I am working with a store that delivers product every Thursday, provided you order by Tuesday 12pm of the same week.

In the notification to the customer, I needed to indicate which Thursday it will ship i.e. 'This' or 'Next' based on order date. I have accomplished that with the following logic in liquid:

```
{% if  date | date: "%A" == 'Tuesday' and date | date: "%k" > 12 %}
   Your order will be delivered on Thursday of next week.
{% elsif date | date: "%A" == 'Wednesday' or date | date: "%A" == 'Thursday' %}
    Your order will be delivered on Thursday of next week.
{% else %}
    Your order will be delivered this Thursday
{% endif %}
```

Above does the job for the moment. However, I've been tasked to actually publish the 'date' of the Thursday of delivery. I've racked my brains and tried to figure out a way where I can write a function in liquid to tell me what 'This' Thursdays date is and what 'Next' Thursdays date will be. But I'm coming up trumps. I know how to do this in PHP and Ruby using the inbuilt functions but I'm new to Liquid and don't think it has inbuilt functions because it's a markup language (. So I would think you'd have to do some unix time math, but that makes it really complex.

Is there another way, or do I have to resort to using some convoluted unix timestamp math?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You will be required to make some unix calculations, but they will be simple ones.

See the code below:

```
{% assign today = 'now' | date: '%s' %}
{% assign single_day = 86400 %}
{% assign today_number = 'now' | date: '%u' | plus: 0 %}

{% if  today_number < 2 %}  

    Delivery by {{ today | plus: single_day | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}

{% else %}

    {% assign days_until_next = 9 | minus: today_number  %}
    {% assign days_unix = days_until_next | times: single_day  %}
    Delivery by {{ today | plus: days_unix  | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}

{% endif %}
```

I will try to break it down.

### Assigning reusable data

`{% assign today = 'now' | date: '%s' %}` - with this we are getting the current unix timestamp for the server date

`{% assign single_day = 86400 %}` - this is the number that defines a single day in unix timestamp

`{% assign today_number = 'now' | date: '%u' | plus: 0 %}` - this returns the current day as a number (1...7). The `plus: 0` is to convert it to a number instead of a string.

### Condition

`{% if  today_number < 2 %}` - we are checking if `today_number` is smaller than 2 ( where 2 is Tuesday ), it can be written in this case like so as well `{% if  today_number == 1 %}`, but you get the logic

### Output

If the above condition is true we do this:

`{{ today | plus: single_day | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}` - this sums the timestamp today and the `single_day` timestamp, giving us the date tomorrow

If the if statement return false we go in the `{% else %}` statement where we set a few variables.

`{% assign days_until_next = 9 | minus: today_number  %}` - since we are counting from the 2nd day I'm using the number 9 as a base and substract the current `today_number` so for example if today is Tuesday, we have 2 and `9-2=7`, so this means the next Tuesday is 7 days from now.

`{% assign days_unix = days_until_next | times: single_day  %}` - this just calculates the single day unix number times the days until the next Tuesday. So if we continue the above Tuesday example you get `86400*7=604800`

`{{ today | plus: days_unix  | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}` - finally we sum the today unix number with the unix number for the days until the next Tuesday and we convert it to a readable date.

Hope that this is simple enough to follow.

Have a great day!

Comment: +1 for actually giving me the code! Fantastic. I was only looking for an opinion on how to leverage any function libraries (if they existed). You've gone above and beyond the call of duty as they say. Lots of good karma coming your way.

Comment: @drip and @djfidelio Hey guys, would just like to warn you that `'now'` isn't always that reliable (it may be better now) but I did something similar to this about 6 months ago and it seems like it was caching or something in the end I had to use javascript to get the correct time.

Comment: @ButsAndCats `now` is getting the server time and yes there is some caching, but it's under a minute. I had to build a site that used time expiration offers and I had to rely on `now` and everything worked like a charm. I don't know if it was broken 6 months ago, but it's working as it should be now. That said, if you are building a clock in liquid, it's better to use JavaScript indeed.

Comment: @drip and @ButsAndCats Thanks for the follow up guys. Yes I have read that using `now`  was giving some outdated time due to caching. I will be using the `order.created_at` to reference the date as that is what the delivery date is based on.